# I need help sorting an array in java based on frequency in this one particular way

Tags: java, frequency

need help taking an an array, counting frequency, putting in another array with array index acting at the number and individual value acting as the frequency in Java

You can sort a large array of m integers that are in the range 1 to n by using an array count of n
entries to count the number of occurrences of each integer in the array. For example, consider
the following array A of 14 integers that are in the range from 1 to 9 (note that in this case m =
14 and n = 9):

```
9 2 4 8 9 4 3 2 8 1 2 7 2 5
```

Form an array count of 9 elements such that count[i-1] contains the number of times that i
occurs in the array to be sorted. Thus, count is

```
1 4 1 2 1 0 1 2 2
```

In particular,

- `count[0] = 1` since 1 occurs once in A.
- count[1] = 4 since 2 occurs 4 times in A.
- count[2]=1 since 3 occurs once in A.
- count[3] =2 since 4 occurs 2 times in A.

Use the count array to sort the original array A. Implement this sorting algorithm in the function

```
public static void countingSort(int[] a, int n )
```

and analyze its worst case running time in terms of m (the length of array a) and n.
After calling countingSort(), a must be a sorted array (do not store sorting result in a
temporary array).

edit: 
this is what i've tried

```
 public static void countingSort1(int[] a, int n) {
    int [] temp = new int[n];
    int [] temp2 = new int[n];
    int visited = -1;
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = index +1; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[index] == a[j]) {
                count++;
                temp[j] = visited;
            }

        }
        if (temp[index]!= visited) {
            temp[index] = count;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (temp[i] != visited) {
            System.out.println("  " +a[i] + "  |   " +temp[i]);
        }
    }
```

Just to count the frequency but i think im doing it wrong

Comment: Share your tries, some code

Comment: do you have to be solve it via counting sort? or you only care about the final array?

Comment: 1. Create a frequency array 'farray' of n elements. And initialize all of the elements in it to zero.
2. for each element 'x' of the original array 'a' increment farray[x].

Note: This will work for small n's. but lets say if n is something like 2000000000 then you will need a lot of memory, most likely allocation will fail

Comment: What is `temp2` used for?

Comment: @AKS *"initialize all of the elements in it to zero"* No need. The array is already initialized to all zeroes by Java.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should do the work:

- Since you already know what the highest value is, in yor example 9,
  create a frequency array with space for nine elements.
- iterate over your input array and for each value you find increase
  the value at the index of the value in your frequency arra by one
- create a counter for the index and initialize it with 0
- iterate over your frequency array in a nested loop and replace the
  values in your input array with the indexes of your frequency array.

I leave the analysis of the complexity to you

```
public static void countingSort(int[] a, int n ){
    //counting
    int[] freq = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        freq[a[i]-1]++;
    }
    //sorting
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< freq.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < freq[i];j++){
            a[index++]= i+1;                
        }            
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```